# Tangent between two circles of equal size with euclidean basic tools.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Given two perpendicular lines with intersection point A. We have two equal sized circles positioned with the centers on the horizontal line. The circles centers are an equal distances from point A. We want to find point P that is the intersection between the vertical line and the lower horizontal tangent between the two circles.

I found link [1](https://www.mathopenref.com/consttangentsext.html) that explains how to find the tangent between two circles in general but my question is if this can be simplified when the circles are of equal size or if there is some other simple way of finding point P.

The distance from A to the center of the circle is not the radius of the circle. The distance is smaller so the circles are overlaping.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not reading your question right, but, if circles have the same radius, wouldn't the tangent to both circles be parallel to the horizontal line?

Comment: And the distance $AP$ is equal to the radius of the circles.

Comment: That is correct, the lines are parallel.

Comment: The distance from A to the center of the circle is not the radius of the circle.

Comment: What do you mean? P is not the centre of a circle. But the distance between A and the point P below it is the same as the length of the radius of either of the circles, wherever they are.

Comment: You are correct. I was just confused. Thank you.